# Permission problems. Can't retrieve inbox messages from dovecot

Tags: centos, permissions, postfix, selinux, dovecot

I got a VPS server at a webhoster which has CentOS 6.6 as operating system.
Because I have multiple domains which are used by various people, this server is going to serve multiple roles:

- nameserver (using BIND) (works!)
- website hoster for multiple domains (using Apache/MySQL) (works!)
- mail server for multiple domains (using postfix, dovecot, vimbadmin & roundcube) (problem)
- FTP server per website (not yet installed)

I use manuals/howto docs from the internet to help me install all roles, since my linux skills aren't that fantastic ;). 
While installing and configuring the mail server for multiple domains (manual: https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/mail/server/postfix-dovecot-ubuntu/) everything went okay. Messages can be sent, but retrieving mail from the mail folder (`/var/vmail/`) is impossible to do. I use a roundcube website as webmail environment.

The error message in the `/var/logs/maillog` file

```
dovecot: imap(mail@address.com): Error: open(/var/vmail/address.com/account/dovecot.index.log) failed: Permission denied (euid=5000(vmail) egid=5000(vmail) missing +r perm: /var/vmail/address.com/account/dovecot.index.log, euid is not dir owner)
dovecot: imap(mail@address.com): Error: file_dotlock_create(/var/vmail/address.com/account/dovecot-uidlist) failed: Permission denied (euid=5000(vmail) egid=5000(vmail) missing +w perm: /var/vmail/address.com/account, euid is not dir owner)
```

permissions on folders/files (`ls -l`)

```
-rw-rwx---. 1 vmail vmail  248 Feb  7 15:52 dovecot.index.log
-rw-rw----. 1 vmail vmail   24 Feb  7 16:32 dovecot.mailbox.log
-rw-rwx---. 1 vmail vmail   51 Feb  7 15:52 dovecot-uidlist
-rw-rwx---. 1 vmail vmail    8 Feb  7 16:32 dovecot-uidvalidity
-r--rwxr--. 1 vmail vmail    0 Feb  7 15:51 dovecot-uidvalidity.54d62668
```

permissions on folders/files (`ls -Z`)

```
-rw-rwx---. vmail vmail unconfined_u:object_r:var_t:s0   dovecot.index.log
-rw-rw----. vmail vmail unconfined_u:object_r:var_t:s0   dovecot.mailbox.log
-rw-rwx---. vmail vmail unconfined_u:object_r:var_t:s0   dovecot-uidlist
-rw-rwx---. vmail vmail unconfined_u:object_r:var_t:s0   dovecot-uidvalidity
-r--rwxr--. vmail vmail unconfined_u:object_r:var_t:s0   dovecot-uidvalidity.54d62668
```

Those permissions are set by the dovecot application after I had created a new mailbox.

Some extra searching lead me to the `setenforce` command. When entering the `setenforce 0` command, I can retrieve mail from the roundcube application. Setting it on again prohibits me from mail retrieval.

But what is going on here? Why can I send messages from the roundcube application without any problems, but mail listing/retrieving messages from an account is impossible with `setenforce 1`. Is it related to the '`unconfined_u`' attribute?

**[2015-02-09] Extra debugging requested**

Debugging using the `grep -i AVC /var/log/audit/audit.log` command shows me the following rows (this is just tail -n-19...)

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1423466977.294:254776): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=13124 comm="imap" name="$myaccount$" dev=dm-0 ino=149839 scontext=system_u:system_r:dovecot_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:var_t:s0 tclass=dir
type=AVC msg=audit(1423466977.294:254777): avc:  denied  { read write } for  pid=13124 comm="imap" name="dovecot-uidlist" dev=dm-0 ino=149846 scontext=system_u:system_r:dovecot_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:var_t:s0 tclass=file
type=AVC msg=audit(1423467003.011:254782): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=13139 comm="imap" name="$myaccount$" dev=dm-0 ino=149839 scontext=system_u:system_r:dovecot_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:var_t:s0 tclass=dir
type=AVC msg=audit(1423467003.011:254783): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=13139 comm="imap" name="$myaccount$" dev=dm-0 ino=149839 scontext=system_u:system_r:dovecot_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:var_t:s0 tclass=dir
type=AVC msg=audit(1423467003.035:254784): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=13139 comm="imap" name="$myaccount$" dev=dm-0 ino=149839 scontext=system_u:system_r:dovecot_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:var_t:s0 tclass=dir
type=AVC msg=audit(1423467003.035:254785): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=13139 comm="imap" name="$myaccount$" dev=dm-0 ino=149839 scontext=system_u:system_r:dovecot_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:var_t:s0 tclass=dir
type=AVC msg=audit(1423467003.093:254786): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=13139 comm="imap" name="tmp" dev=dm-0 ino=415518 scontext=system_u:system_r:dovecot_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:var_t:s0 tclass=dir
type=AVC msg=audit(1423467003.093:254787): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=13139 comm="imap" name="cur" dev=dm-0 ino=415516 scontext=system_u:system_r:dovecot_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:var_t:s0 tclass=dir
type=AVC msg=audit(1423467003.093:254788): avc:  denied  { read write } for  pid=13139 comm="imap" name="dovecot.index.log" dev=dm-0 ino=149840 scontext=system_u:system_r:dovecot_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:var_t:s0 tclass=file
type=AVC msg=audit(1423467003.093:254789): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=13139 comm="imap" name="dovecot.index.log" dev=dm-0 ino=149840 scontext=system_u:system_r:dovecot_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:var_t:s0 tclass=file
type=AVC msg=audit(1423467003.093:254790): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=13139 comm="imap" name="$myaccount$" dev=dm-0 ino=149839 scontext=system_u:system_r:dovecot_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:var_t:s0 tclass=dir
type=AVC msg=audit(1423467003.094:254791): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=13139 comm="imap" name="$myaccount$" dev=dm-0 ino=149839 scontext=system_u:system_r:dovecot_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:var_t:s0 tclass=dir
type=AVC msg=audit(1423467003.094:254792): avc:  denied  { read write } for  pid=13139 comm="imap" name="dovecot-uidlist" dev=dm-0 ino=149846 scontext=system_u:system_r:dovecot_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:var_t:s0 tclass=file
type=AVC msg=audit(1423467003.206:254793): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=13139 comm="imap" name="tmp" dev=dm-0 ino=415518 scontext=system_u:system_r:dovecot_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:var_t:s0 tclass=dir
type=AVC msg=audit(1423467003.207:254794): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=13139 comm="imap" name="cur" dev=dm-0 ino=415516 scontext=system_u:system_r:dovecot_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:var_t:s0 tclass=dir
type=AVC msg=audit(1423467003.207:254795): avc:  denied  { read write } for  pid=13139 comm="imap" name="dovecot.index.log" dev=dm-0 ino=149840 scontext=system_u:system_r:dovecot_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:var_t:s0 tclass=file
type=AVC msg=audit(1423467003.207:254796): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=13139 comm="imap" name="dovecot.index.log" dev=dm-0 ino=149840 scontext=system_u:system_r:dovecot_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:var_t:s0 tclass=file
type=AVC msg=audit(1423467003.207:254797): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=13139 comm="imap" name="$myaccount$" dev=dm-0 ino=149839 scontext=system_u:system_r:dovecot_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:var_t:s0 tclass=dir
type=AVC msg=audit(1423467003.208:254798): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=13139 comm="imap" name="$myaccount$" dev=dm-0 ino=149839 scontext=system_u:system_r:dovecot_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:var_t:s0 tclass=dir
type=AVC msg=audit(1423467003.208:254799): avc:  denied  { read write } for  pid=13139 comm="imap" name="dovecot-uidlist" dev=dm-0 ino=149846 scontext=system_u:system_r:dovecot_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:var_t:s0 tclass=file
```

Comment: From [WhyDoesItNotWork page of Dovecot](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/WhyDoesItNotWork), the author mentioning that you should check audit.log (by run `grep -i AVC /var/log/audit/audit.log`) to see any other messages regarding SELinux. Please edit the question and post the output.

Comment: @masegaloeh I added the error logging like you asked!

Comment: Check the permissions not only on individual files inside a mailbox, but also on folders all the way up to the home directory. So for example on `/var/vmail/address.com/account/mdbox/mailboxes/INBOX/dovecot.index.log` and on the `INBOX` directory and on the `mailboxes` directory, and so on up to the home `/var/vmail/address.com/account`.

Comment: @Celada The permissions from the /var/vmail folder to the dovecot.index.log file for directories: 'drwxrwx--x' and for files '[see question..]'

Answer (score 1):

Can you set SElinux to permissive mode and try if it works?

```
sudo setenforce permissive
```

The SElinux policies seems to be wrong. The policy should be:

```
   drwx------. vmail vmail system_u:object_r:mail_spool_t:s0 example.org
```

You can set the policies correct by

```
sudo semanage fcontext -a -t mail_spool_t "/var/vmail(/.*)?"
sudo restorecon -Rv /var/vmail
```